# .net core allowing sending back error 401 when using CORS (instead of zero)

Tags: api, asp.net-core, cors, http-status-codes

My client JS app is receiving status code 0 when it is actually 401.
When I use postman for running the same request i am getting 401 as expected.

I have enabled cors as the following:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("cors", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowCredentials();
            }));

....
app.UseCors("cors");
```

The cors is working when there is no authentication problem (401).

I am getting error code 0 in the client-side when it is supposed to be 401.

[image]

Comment: Postman does not care about CORS so it'd work there no matter what :)

Comment: @juunas I stated that to clearify that 401 does return from the server

Comment: Did you check all the headers* sent by Postman, and tried to put exactly the same in your JS request?
* in the tab Headers, unfold the "Temporary Headers" to see everything Postman send without you have explicity set them

Comment: @GuillaumeSasdy The browser network tab is showing 401. but in the JS it is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this error is a most likely a combination of CORS on your server and the web browser.

**Cause:** My guess is, some of the required CORS headers are missing from your server response. Browsers return a status of 0 when incorrect Cors headers are used.

**Solution:** Again I will guess the order you are registering your middleware is incorrect. 
As per the docs:

> With endpoint routing, the CORS middleware must be configured to
>   execute between the calls to UseRouting and UseEndpoints. Incorrect
>   configuration will cause the middleware to stop functioning correctly.

I would register you middleware in an order like so (depending on what middlewares you're using):

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("cors");
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
...
//register app.UseMvc(); last
```