# Why I'm having CORS error when calling an API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors

I'm using `Angular` in frontend and `C#` as my backend, I got this error when I try to edit fields and save it:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.220.14:81/api/registry' from origin 'http://artc.tj' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

PUT http://192.168.220.14:81/api/reg polyfills-es2015.23e79c711e3c227d781f.js:1 PUT http://192.168.220.14:81/api/registry net::ERR_FAILED
```

[Error Scrinshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yarq.png)

**Startup.cs:**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     //CORS
     services.AddCors(options =>
     {
         options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
         builder =>
         {
             builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost",
                                 "http://localhost:4200",
                                 "http://artc.tj",
                                 "http://192.168.220.14")
                                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowCredentials();
         });
     });
  }
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: have you added `app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins); ` in configure method?

Comment: I guess you are registering your middleware too late. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60038513/5517088

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET 5/Core/vNext CORS not working even if allowing pretty much everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138196/asp-net-5-core-vnext-cors-not-working-even-if-allowing-pretty-much-everything)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the `Cors()` in your `Configure` method.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
   //...
   readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      //...
         services.AddCors(options =>
         {
             options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
             builder =>
             {
                 builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                     .AllowAnyHeader()
                     .AllowAnyMethod()
                     .AllowAnyOrigin();
             });
         });
      //...
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
      //...
      app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
      //...
   }
   //...
}
```

P.S. Also make sure to include `withCredentials: false` in your client request `httpOptions`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the header when sending the request from `Angular` side. Here's what I normally do:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddCors(options =>
     {
         options.AddPolicy("Default", policy =>
         {
             policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod();
         });
     });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("Default");
}
```

**Angular Request:**

```
callAPI() {
   return this.httpClient
            .get(API_URL, {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'}});
}
```

Comment: The client doesn't decide who the server gives access to. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header sent from the server

Answer (score -1):

You don't. The server you are making the request to has to implement CORS to grant JavaScript from your website access. Your JavaScript can't grant itself permission to access another website.

Use a CORS extension from web store of chrome browser.

Hope so this might change your perceotion